# How to convert Lua userdata to C++ class object?

Tags: c++, lua, luabridge

I have this Lua code:

```
function returnPerson()
    local person = Person("Mike", 23)     
    return person
end
```

It returns userdata representing Person(C++ class registered using LuaBridge). So I call this function using lua_pcall and now the last element of the lua stack is that userdata. My question is how do I convert(cast) this userdata at -1 back to Person in C++.

I tried this, but it just terminates the program:

```
LuaRef lref_p(l);

lref_p.fromStack(l, -1);

Person pers = lref_p.cast<Person>();
```

I hope it makes sense :)

Comment: try `Person pers = *lref_p.cast<Person *>();`

Comment: Nope, still not working!  @rpattiso

Comment: An [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and description of how it terminates (with what error message) would be great.

Comment: @rpattiso After hours of tweaking and trying I found the solution
`lref_p.fromStack(l, -1);` should be replaced with `lref_p = LuaRef::fromStack(l, -1)`

Also I found an easier way of doing this:
`Person *pers = luabridge::Userdata::get<Person>(l, 1, false);`

Comment: Great, that looks cleaner too. You can post your solution as an answer.

Comment: @rpattiso Do you have any idea though, why as the second argument here `get<Person>(l, 1, false)` I had to use 1 instead of -1 as that parameter should be the index on the stack. The function has `assert(index > 0)` I have no idea why.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

OK, so after hours of tweaking and trying I found the solution. It was the second line: `lref_p.fromStack(l, -1);` that was the problem. It should be `lref_p = LuaRef::fromStack(l, -1);`

Also I found an easier and cleaner way of doing this:

`Person *pers = luabridge::Userdata::get<Person>(l, 1, false);`